# According to Christians that believe in Evolution, when did people start getting Souls?

Tags: creation, souls, evolution

Let me start by saying I personally believe in evolution and the science of evolution.  I believe Genesis is a description of this in a way that was able to be understood at the time it was written, and God of course is the creator of it all.

But that led me to wonder that if all life on Earth came from the same place so long ago, but not everything has a soul, then when exactly did we get souls?  At what point in our evolutionary chain did God start giving our ancestors souls?

There are those that say Adam and Eve were the first to have souls.  If that is so, then what species exactly were Adam and Eve?

There are also those who say that souls evolved just as everything else did.  But then if that is so, how exactly does a soul 'evolve', and why is it believed then that not everything has a soul?

Comment: There are an awful lot of questions in your post. I strongly suggest focusing on one and writing your post around that one specifically. If that raises other questions in your mind, write separate questions for those!